# How to get dropdown selected value for each dynamic generated components in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I have created dynamic component with dropdown as showing in following code and this component generated dynamically on button click "Add" button.

```
<select class="form-control" name="Origins">
    <option *ngFor="let CodeListPort of port" value="{{CodeListPort.codeListPortID}}">{{CodeListPort.codeListPortID}}</option> </select>
```

Each time when I click on "Add" button new instance of same component added. I am able to bind the value but don't know how to get the value from dynamically generated component.

Please suggest if someone has faced this issue.

Comment: You should use ReactiveForms with FormArray: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray

Comment: @Fals Do you have any plnkr example or any blog which helps me to come out in this.

Comment: The angular website has: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form